# Looping card game, keeping values, till user wants to quit - Python 3

Tags: loops, python-3.x, return-value

I'm new to programming, and I can't find the answer to my question yet. I wrote a program for a card game that's a betting game, using functions. However, at the end of each round I want to ask the user if they want to keep playing. How do I do this? Also, I want to keep previous values generated if they go want to keep playing, but again, I don't know how. Thanks for any help!

This is the code that I'm using currently, but it will only display the option to play again after running the code straight through twice

```
main () 
answer = 'y'
while answer.lower() == 'y':
    main()
    answer = input("do you wish to play again? (y/n)")
    if answer.lower() == 'n':
        break 
print("the end")
```

Comment: What have you tried? It should be easy enough to wrap your code in a `while` loop so that it keeps running the game over and over until some condition is met. If you've tried it and run into problems, ask about them (and show your code!).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this-

```
n<-input

while(n!=somevalue)
    keep_playing_game
    n<-input
```

P.S- This is generic code.